# MySQL how to replace URL only and keep the filename

Tags: php, mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Recently I've switched from AWS S3 to CloudFront. But I have a problem in my database. old URLS still exists.

As shown in the picture:

[image]

What is the correct sql query to change the URL of S3 to the Cloudfront and keep the file name?

Example:

```
replace http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/2sale/1502039625_467b81ba-2dea-4572-ad47-c021fe13de67.jpg

to 
https://XXXX.cloudfront.net/1502039625_467b81ba-2dea-4572-ad47-c021fe13de67.jpg
```

For all image_url rows.

Comment: This one for exists database URLs I just need a query, that question regarding while posting to S3 need to change to CloudFront. those are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MySQL` replace:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, 'http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/2sale/', 'https://XXXX.cloudfront.net/')
WHERE your_field LIKE 'http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/2sale/%'
```

Reference: https://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-find-replace-text/

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`Search and replace`](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-find-replace-text/)

> Syntax

```
UPDATE `table_name`
 SET `field_name` = replace(same_field_name, 'unwanted_text', 'wanted_text')
```

> In Your case

```
UPDATE `table_name`
     SET `field_name` = replace(image_url, 'http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/2sale/', 'https://XXXX.cloudfront.net/')
```

**You can also add the where condition if want to replace only specific record value**